# printer drivers are included by default in Windows XP - can't install in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, printer

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/293380, Windows XP includes built-in drivers for Kyocera FS-9000 printers.  Windows 7, however, does not seem to.  This is a problem for me since I have one of these printers.

Any ideas as to what options I have?  Thanks!

Comment: 32 or 64bit Windows 7?

Comment: 64-bit.  I tried the 32-bit and 64-bit drivers from the link ngen provided to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tired downloading the Windows 7 drivers from their website?

http://www.kyoceramita.eu/index/service/dlc.false.driver.FS9000._.EN.html

Comment: I can't figure out for the life of me how to get those drivers to work.

Answer (score 1):

Go to 'Add a printer'.
Select if it's local or not.
Select the port or the printer.
Then you'll see a list with brands, select 'Kyocera'.
In the right hand column you'll see some types, but yours won't be in it at this point.
Click 'Windows Update'.
Normally, your printer should be listed there.
The rest you can figure out yourself, I guess.

Note: I only did this with USB connection. I can't guarantee it works with a print server.

Answer (score 0):

When I try the 64-bit drivers the following new printers appear under Kyocera:

Kyocera Classic Universaldriver

Kyocera Classic Universaldriver (A4 models)

Neither seem to work for the Kyocera FS-9000 printer however.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in advance if you've tried this already or it's stating the obvious, but when I tried to get my printer (an old Laserjet 3200) working in Windows 7, it wasn't there either.  I did all sorts of digging into old drivers, screwy workarounds, etc. until I finally came across a post somewhere that said something like "Uh, why don't you just click on the "Windows Update" button in the add printer dialog?"

So I did, waited a minute or two for it to populate and, voila, there it was.  Felt like an idiot, but it worked.

Start, Devices and printers, Add a printer, Add a local printer, Use an existing port, click on Windows Update, wait a minute, then check the list again.